# UIButton and actions problem

Tags: iphone, uibutton, ibaction

I am creating some UIbutton dynamically. And a user click any one of the buttons will display something (ex: different views). So I successfully made the buttons, get the tags. But in the IBAction method below, because all these buttons are dynamically created. So I can't use if, else if statement to show the view based on the tag number. I am thinking of using loops? any ideas?

Here is my code:

`NSMutableArray *buttonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];`

```
for(int i = 0; i < [someArray count]; i++)
{
      button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(btnX,btnY,btnW,btnH)];

    button.tag = i;

    [buttonsArray addObject:button];

    [[buttonsArray objectAtIndex:i] addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    button.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Click it"];

    [self.view addSubview:button];

    btnY = btnY + 120;
}

`-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender `
{

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"%ld", btn.tag);

      //Don't know the number of buttons, so this is not gonna work
    if( btn.tag == 1)
    {
            //do something
    }
        if( btn.tag == 2)
    {
            //do something
    }
    if( btn.tag == 3)
    {
            //do something
    }
    if( btn.tag == 4)
    {
            //do something
    }

}
```

Comment: what you want to display when a button will be clicked?

Comment: You can use switch statement instead of putting if..else.if.. conditions

Comment: at some point you have to map your implementation to the buttons you have created. From the code i can see that you determine the number of buttons based upon an array so you know how many buttons you have. why not have a dictionary where the key is the button tag and the value is a selector or some other data structure that will indicate what you want to achieve. This way when you get the tag of a button just get the value for the key from the dictionary and use that. this also means you wont need a load of horrible if statements, or a huge switch statement

Comment: if a button is clicked it will show a view, if other button is click it will show a different view

Comment: Sorry Kevin :) I apologies for that.

Comment: so what view will it show, is each view shown an entirely different view, why don't you know how many buttons there will be. I think there are some more fundamental design issues here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loop is not the perfect solution here i think...agree with Jennis...use switch instead of if else statement...if you want to use loop try:

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender{
UIButton *selectedbtn = (UIButton *)sender;
for (UIButton *bttn in buttonsArray) {       
    if ([bttn.tag == selectedbtn.tag ) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

}

Comment: could you just use if ([buttonsArray containsObject:sender]) after all its just an id ?? that way you could dispense with the for loop altogether, but fundamentally i dont see what this gives you, you are just affirming that a button was added to an array, as the OP sets the target and action from the actual array itself, surely the fact that the IBAction is called means it was added to the array

Answer (score 0):

you get Multiple UIbutton ? b'coz your X and Y are same for all..

Comment: i think he is doing that in the last statement of the loop btnY = btnY + 120;

Answer (score 0):

All is OK in your code except two things.

(1) Change the coordinates of buttons so you get different position for all the buttons in the view.

(2) Change the following code:

```
[[buttonsArray objectAtIndex:i] addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

with this code:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Let me know if any further help required.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. also, because his buttons are contained in the array, it really doesn't make much difference where the target is added, he is still adding it to the button, i'd perhaps agree that the target should be added before adding to the array but his question is about how to link a tag to the loading of a view not whether the code is correct or not..